# Why is calling Box-ed closure requires unstable fn_traits?

Tags: pointers, rust, closures

Consider the following code:

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]
fn test_fn_2_args<F>(f: Box<F>)
where
    F: Fn(i32, i64) -> i32
{
    <Box<F> as Fn<(i32, i64)>>::call(&f, (1, 2));
}

fn main(){
    test_fn_2_args(Box::new(|first, second| {
       println!("{first}, {second}");
       first
    }));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0c7c6ee86d1aee99a27a58d1c8296139)

This code requires unstable `fn_traits`, but this is not clear why. As per [fn_traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/library-features/fn-traits.html) docs it's designed for implementing closure-like type which I don't do in this example.

All I do is interpret `Box<Fn>` as `Fn` which is not clear why is allowed as well since `Box<Fn>` does not implement `Fn` obviously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling a boxed closure, does not require unstable. To call it, you simply use the standard calling syntax (i.e. a [call expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/call-expr.html)) to call it. Boxed or not.

It doesn't matter whether you have `Fn()` or `Box<dyn Fn()>` you call it in the same way, i.e. `f()`.

The reason you can call them in the same way, is because there is a [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html?highlight=blanket%20implementation#blanket-implementation) of [`impl<F> Fn for Box<F> where F: Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Fn%3CArgs%3E-for-Box%3CF,+A%3E).

The reason you can use [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), but not [`Fn::call()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#tymethod.call) is because [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) is stable, while [`Fn::call()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#tymethod.call) is unstable. Which as you've discovered is part of the unstable [`fn_traits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/library-features/fn-traits.html) feature (see [issue #29625](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29625)).

So the issue is not *"interpreting `Box<Fn>` as `Fn`"*, the issue is you're attempting to call the unstable [`Fn::call()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html#tymethod.call).

In short, doing this is stable:

```rust
fn f<F: Fn()>(f: F) {
    f();
}

fn boxed_f<F: Fn()>(f: Box<F>) {
    f();
}
```

While doing the following is unstable:

```rust
fn f<F: Fn()>(f: F) {
    Fn::<()>::call(&f, ());
}

fn boxed_f<F: Fn()>(f: Box<F>) {
    Fn::<()>::call(&f, ());
}
```

All in all, just *call* the closure like any other function:

```rust
fn test_fn_2_args<F>(f: Box<F>)
where
    F: Fn(i32, i64) -> i32,
{
    f(1, 2);
}
```

You don't even need `Box`:

```rust
fn test_fn_2_args<F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn(i32, i64) -> i32,
{
    f(1, 2);
}
```

Again, since there is a [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/glossary.html?highlight=blanket%20implementation#blanket-implementation) of [`impl<F> Fn for Box<F> where F: Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Fn%3CArgs%3E-for-Box%3CF,+A%3E). That also means that changing `test_fn_2_args()` to not use `Box`, still allows you to call it using a boxed closure. So the following compiles perfectly fine.

```rust
fn test_fn_2_args<F>(f: F)
where
    F: Fn(i32, i64) -> i32,
{
    f(1, 2);
}

fn main() {
    test_fn_2_args(|first, second| {
        println!("{first}, {second}");
        first
    });

    test_fn_2_args(Box::new(|first, second| {
        println!("{first}, {second}");
        first
    }));
}
```